# Playonlinux can be executed on UBUNTU MATE?

Tags: ubuntu-mate

when i viewed the «can i install playonlinux on ubuntu» and then the answer was yes
so if worked with ubuntu can work with ubuntu MATE too?

if anyone answered it would be great

Comment: play on linux works on all linux distros that have a desktop installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PlayOnLinux is a front-end for wine. It permits you to easily install Windows games and software on Linux.

PlayOnLinux is compatible with all currently supported versions of Ubuntu that have a desktop environment installed, including Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: but now how i put internet on ubuntu mate? hehe im a noob

Comment: Ubuntu MATE should be connected to internet via ethernet by default, but wireless networking needs to be configured. Open the terminal and run the command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`  and also `lsusb` to identify your wireless adapter, and then post it as a separate question.

Comment: man your the best

Comment: ok i clicked in the check